# Title Not Showing in Simulator and doesn't shift ViewController to next after button click

Tags: swift, xcode

Title is not showing in Simulator

```
import UIKit
```

class WelcomeSpotifyViewController: UIViewController {

```
private let signInButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.setTitle("Sign In with Spotify", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Spotify"
    view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    view.addSubview(signInButton)
    signInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    signInButton.frame = CGRect(x:20, y: view.height-50-view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, width: view.width-40, height: 50)
}

@objc func didTapSignIn() {
    let vc = SpotifyAuthViewController()
    vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

}

When I launch the simulator, the title does not show. And when I click the button "Sign In with Spotify," I do not transfer to the SpotifyAuthViewController.

Here is the code for the SpotifyAuthViewController

```
import UIKit
```

import WebKit

class SpotifyAuthViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

```
private let webView: WKWebView = {
    let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
    prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    
    return webView
    
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Sign In"
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)

  
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    webView.frame = view.bounds


}
```

}

After the user is registered, I want them to be directed to a standard login/register page where they create a username, register with email, and create a password.

```
import UIKit
```

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

```
private let usernameEmailField: UITextField = {
    return UITextField()
}()

private let passwordField: UITextField = {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    return field
}()

private let loginButton: UIButton = {
    return UIButton()
}()


private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
    return UIButton()
}()




private let headerView: UIView = {
    return UIView()
}()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSubviews()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    handleNotAuthenticated()
    
    
    //Check auth status
    
    
}

private func handleNotAuthenticated() {
    if SpotifyAuthManager.shared.isSignedIn == false {
        let loginVC = WelcomeSpotifyViewController()
        loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(loginVC, animated: false)
}
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    //assign frames
}

private func addSubviews() {
    view.addSubview(usernameEmailField)
    view.addSubview(createAccountButton)
    view.addSubview(passwordField)
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    view.addSubview(headerView)
}



@objc private func didTabLoginButton(){}
@objc private func didTapCreateAccountButton(){}

}
```

If the user is not connected with Spotify, then they are redirected to the WelcomeSpotifyViewController. Once they enter their username and pass, they are taken to the home page.

```
import UIKit
```

import FirebaseAuth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    handleNotAuthenticated()
    
    
    //Check auth status
    
    
}

private func handleNotAuthenticated() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let loginVC = LoginViewController()
        loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(loginVC, animated: false)
}
}
```

}

I have been tinkering with this for days now. I can't seem to figure out the issue. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your WelcomeSpotifyViewController don't have navigaiton controller. You should debug and check value of navigation controller